# wordpress use in subdirecotory show Oops! That page can’t be found

Tags: wordpress

I have installed wordpress in `pcm` directory at my document root `/home/dinuka/workspace`. I had given pcm.dev as its domain. It is working good in my machine.

Now i want to use this site in subdirectory in main domain like `test.com/pcm`. So i tried to it locally first.

My document root /home/dinuka/workspace has a domain `works.dev` . Now i want this project as `works.dev/pcm`

I refer http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

I change `WordPress address` and `Site address` as in **Moving a Root install to its own directory section**

I didn't try to change .htaccss. Now `works.dev/pcm/wp-admin.php` is working good. But `works.dev/pcm` show **Oops! That page can’t be found.** message in wordpress theme layout.

This question should duplicate. But i coudn't find the correct solution.

Comment: What about if you try open works.dev/pcm/index.php , does this work ?

Comment: No it is redirect to works.dev/pcm